# Make an Outer Div clickable that contains an iFrame using Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a html snippet that is generated dynamically using AJAX.

```
<div class="ad_frame">
<iframe class="inner_frame" src="some_url" frameborder="0" width="100" height="100"></iframe>
</div>
```

I want to make the div ad_frame clickable using javascript. Here is my code that works well except for the outer div scenario.

```
$(document).on('click', '.ad_frame', function(){    
        alert("Hurray! Outer div ad_frame is clicked.");
    });
```

This problem doesn't seem around Javascript. May be I am missing something with outer div styling. Not sure.

Comment: `$('.ad_frame').on('click', function() {    
    alert("Hurray! Outer div ad_frame is clicked.");
});`

This should help!

Comment: your codes seem OK. add css styles for `.ad_frame {
  padding:2px;
  background-color:red;
}`, then click at the area colored on RED